# Power Macintosh G4 won't boot after plugging in an external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, startup, powerpc, power-mac

Last weekend I got an old PowerMac G4 "Gigabit Ethernet" and it worked fine for a few hours. Then after plugging in my external HDD to copy some of the data over, the system went to sleep and wouldn't turn back on. I proceeded to turn off the Mac and unplug the HDD; once I rebooted, I was met with a long load time (about two minutes) with no Apple on the light-gray screen -- followed by the Finder icon with a question mark.

I looked up articles and forums to help, but so far nothing has worked. I have tried pressing Alt+R (Command+R) to get into the recovery menu -- and while the menu does appear just fine, there's no option for anything to boot from; it just shows me the "reload" icon and an arrow pointing to the right.

Another thing I tried doing was I burned an .iso of Mac OS X Tiger (the Power Mac has 10.4.11) and try loading that from Recovery mode, but it still does nothing; the disc doesn't appear in the menu. In fact, the disc barely spins in the drive; the LED just blinks a few times when the system powers on, then quickly stops trying to read the disc.

The only thing I can think to do now is go into OpenFirmware (I do this by pressing one of the buttons below Power), but I haven't found a solution that works here. I might try booting from the CD, but if the CD didn't show up in the Recovery mode, I doubt it would show up in OpenFirmware.

While in OpenFirmware, I went and entered a few commands, as advised by [@Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan). Here is the output from `devalias`:

```
pci0              /pci@f0000000
agp               /pci@f0000000
pci1              /pci@f2000000
pci2              /pci@f4000000
pci               /pci@f2000000
fwx               /pci@f2000000/firewire@12
enetx             /pci@f2000000/ethernet@13
enet1             /pci@f2000000/ethernet
fw1               /pci@f2000000/firewire
cb                /pci@f2000000/cardbus@1a
cbx               /pci@f2000000/cardbus@1a/pci-bridge/pci-bridge
usb0              /pci@f2000000/usb@18
usb1              /pci@f2000000/usb@19
mac-io            /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17
mpic              /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/interrupt-controller
ide0              /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/ata-3@20000/disk@0
ide1              /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/ata-3@20000/disk@1
hd                /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/ata-4@1f000/disk@0
cd                /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/ata-3@20000/disk@0
zip               /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/ata-3@20000/disk@1
ultra0            /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/ata-4@1f000/disk@0
ultra1            /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/ata-4@1f000/disk@1
scca              /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/escc/ch-a
sccb              /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/escc/ch-b
ki2c              /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/i2c
ki2c-serial       /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/i2c/cereal
via-pmu           /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/via-pmu
rtc               /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/via-pmu/rtc
adb               /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/via-pmu/adb
adb-keyboard      /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/via-pmu/adb/keyboard
adb-mouse         /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/via-pmu/adb/mouse
adb-eject-key     /pci@f2000000/mac-io@17/via-pmu/adb/eject-key
wireless          /pci@f2000000/nac-io@17/@30000
ui2c              /uni-n/i2c
ui2c-serial       /uni-n/i2c/cereal
enet              /pci@f4000000/ethernet
fw                /pci@f4000000/firewire
keyboard          /pseudo-hid/keyboard
mouse             /pseudo-hid/mouse
nvram             /nvram
sound             /pseudo-sound
eject-key         /pseudo-hide/object-key
last-boot         /pci@f4000000/ethernet@f
screen            /pci@f4000000/ATV ,Rage 128Pd@ 10
```

Entering the command `printenv` yielded this result:

```
-------------- Partition: common -------- Signature: 0x70 --------------
little-endian?          false                false
real-mode?              false                false
auto-boot?              true                 true
diag-switch?            false                false
fcode-debug?            false                false
oem-banner?             false                false
oem-logo?               false                false
use-nvramrc?            false                false
use-generic?            false                false
default-mac-address?    false                false
real-base               -1                   -1
real-size               -1                   -1
load-base               0x800000             0x800000
virt-base               -1                   -1
virt-size               -1                   -1
pci-probe-mask          -1                   -1
screen-#columns         100                  100
screen-#rows            40                   40
selftest-#megs          0                    0
boot-device             hd:,\\:tbxi          hd:,\\:tbxi
boot-file            
boot-screen          
console-screen       
diag-device             enet                 enet
diag-file               ,diags               ,diags
input-device            keyboard             keyboard
output-device           screen               screen
input-device-1          scca                 scaa
output-device-1         scca                 scaa
mouse-device            mouse                mouse
oem-banner       
oem-logo            
nvramrc             
boot-command            mac-boot             mac-boot
default-client-ip       
default-server-ip       
default-gateway-ip      
default-subnet-mask     
boot-script            
aapl,pci                Use PRINT-APPL,PCI to view
ram-size                30783430 30303030 3030
```

So, **TL;DR -** because I stuck a USB device into my PowerMac, it has forgotten where the boot sector is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112093/discussion-on-question-by-freerey-power-macintosh-g4-wont-boot-after-plugging-i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after buying another Mac with some install discs, I have concluded that there was something wrong with the master HDD, as it would not allow me to install the new system over the old one unless I wiped that disk completely. So I have gone and done just that.

I wish there was a way to do this without removing all data, but that doesn't seem to be the case. In any event, **recovery/install discs are your friend and they saved me here**. Huge thanks to everyone who helped out in this endeavor (especially Allan)!

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the PRAM with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Keep the keys pressed until 5 reset cycles (beeps) are completed.

Comment: I will try this when I get home, thank you. I wanna ask, though, what difference would holding it down for 5 cycles make?

Comment: the old trick of zapping PRAM for 3-5 "bongs" is mostly a "why not" step. I've only seen people's *claims* that letting a PRAM zap 3-5 times in a row fixed an issue where one did not. It's one of those, "it only takes a few extra seconds, so why not." All that said I usually let it bong 3 times for no other reason than "it's quick and easy."

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that the USB is v1.1 (12Mbps!) so not realistic for attaching a drive. Also, it doesn't have "Recovery", which is a menu for accessing Disk Utility and Installing the OS - it just has a choice of boot options when you hold Alt.

You can force it to boot from the DVD by holding down C.

You can boot into OpenFirware with Command Alt O F, if memory serves.

Some useful info about Open Firmware is here:

http://macos9lives.com/smforum/index.php?topic=1965.0

Another possibility is a FireWire external drive, but that might be difficult to configure if this is your only Mac.

If the hard drive and DVD both won't boot, then I'd say the problem is further up the chain. It could be the cables inside, or just old age.

Answer (score 0):

it's looking for a startup HD that isn't present.

hold down OPTION at startup and choose your boot disk, then set the startup disk using system preferences -> startup disk.

make sure when you select the startup disk, its highlighted.

zapping the PRAM before you do this is helpful.

onboard battery may be dead - which means settings get lost when power to the system is interrupted.